# OpenMP SIMD: Nested loops

Tags: c, openmp, vectorization, simd

I want to use SIMD vectorization for Fourier transformations of an inplaced calculated function. It can be summerized as:

```
double f_1(int s);        // expensive
double f_2(int s, int k); // cheap but frequent

void accumulate(double *sum, int samples, int freqs) {
  for (int s=0; s<samples; s++) {
    double data = f_1(s);
    for (int k=0; k<freqs; k++)
      sum[k] += data * f_2(s, k);
  }
}
```

The streight forward way would be to parallelize over the outher loop s with an reduction on sum[k], but its immediate size would overflow the cache. Just vectorizing the inner loop however will not improve the costly function f_1. Is there a good way to get both, a vectorization of f_1 over s and the accumulation over k? Best if possible with OpenMP without chunking the loops manually.

Edit:
The best way I've found so far is manual chunking. However refactoring the code in such a way is a major task. It verctorizes f_1 well, but gcc seems to not like to do so for f_2. Maybe a bug through...

```
#pragma omp declare simd linear(s)
double f_1(int s);        // expensive

#pragma omp declare simd uniform(s) linear(k)
double f_2(int s, int k); // cheap but frequent

void accumulate(double *sum, int samples, int freqs) {
  const int N = 8;
  for (int s=0; s<samples; s+=N) {
    double data[N];
    #pragma omp simd
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
      data[i] = f_1(s+i);
    #pragma omp simd safelen(N)
    for (int k=0; k<freqs; k++) {
      for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        sum[k] += data[i] * f_2(s+i, k);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Depending on how expensive the functions are, it might be better to do the outer loop using an OpenMP parallel for instead. Threads for outer loops and SIMD for inner loops can be a great combination. `data[0]` in your second snippet seems wrong; are you sure it shouldn't be `data[i]`? What about adding an omp simd declaration to the inner loop in the second snippet, too?

Comment: @nemequ Indeed, the data[0] was a typo. What is the effect on stacked pragma omp simd declarations? The outer look isn't expensive enough for threads, it is even less expensive than f2*freqs. But expensive enough to care about it.

Comment: Not sure if "stacked" means nested or consecutive, but neither is a problem. The compiler may or may not be able to generate SIMD code, of course, but that's true for non-nested loops too.

Comment: #pragma omp parallel for at s-loop and #pragma omp simd at k-loop (as suggested above) is at least worth trying and comparing against other options.   Alternate approach, discussed by you, is an outer loop vectorization whose success depends on memory access pattern  from both s and k induction variable perspectives (did you look at it?). This may help to cache utilization as well (what is a footprint of s-loop?) Finally, outer loop vectorization is sophisticated optimization, so I would look at icc or , perhaps, clang performance.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to test the compiler's auto-vectorizer capability as well. In my experience OpenMP SIMD capability was not efficient as compilers are. Thus, I would like to tell you to use -Ofast flag in compile command to see the benefits

Comment: Because you are using double data type only the O3 is not enough. you should tell the the compiler to ignore floating point obstacles such as high precision is not important for you by using -Ofast flag. **IMPORTANT** : Loop counters should be constant for autovectorizer